# Convert an object into list or array MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, arraylist, hashtable

I have an MVC grid control that is passing back the collection to my controller as an object.
The object is an ArrayList of the rows from the grid and each row is a List that represents an instance of a class called lineitem that is part of a parent record class.

I am trying to load the object into the class by looping through the object array, create an instance of my lineitem class, and then add it to my parent record class parent.AddItem(lineitem).  I originally had it created as follows

```
var items = requestData.ExtraRequestData["Items"];
```

However As I determined, it was an ArrayList I changed that to

```
List<string> mylist;    
ArrayList items = (ArrayList)requestData.ExtraRequestData["Items"];
mylist = items.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

I am trying to convert the ArrayList into a List so I can loop through it and load it into my class.

```
Model.Parent parent = new Model.Parent();
Model.LineItem lineitem = new Model.LineItem();

for (int I = 0; I < mylist.length; I++){

       lineitem.a = item.a,
       lineitem.b = item.b
parent.AddItem(lineitem)
}
```

I am getting the following error on the line where I set mylist = items:

```
{"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Hashtable' to type 'System.String'."}
```

What am I missing to convert this so I can load it into my class?

Comment: If you show some code that will be helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each item in the ArrayList was a hashtable, I ended up looping through it as follows:
  ParentClass ReconHdr = new ParentClass();

```
            foreach (System.Collections.Hashtable  o in items)
            {
               //lineItem.LineSeq = Convert.ToInt32(item.Value);
                ArrayList list = new ArrayList(o.Values);
                ChildClass lineItem = new ChildClass();

                lineItem.StmntDocNum = list[0].ToString();
                lineItem.PrtlAmt = Convert.ToDouble(list[1]);
                lineItem.GLAcctCode = list[2].ToString();
                lineItem.LineSeq = Convert.ToInt32(list[3]);
                lineItem.ClinicID = Convert.ToInt32(list[4]);
                lineItem.PrtlTranDate = Convert.ToDateTime(list[5]);
                lineItem.StmntTranDate = Convert.ToDateTime(list[6]);
                lineItem.PrtlFinRptDate = Convert.ToDateTime(list[7]);
                lineItem.StmntEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(list[8]);
                lineItem.StmntAmt = Convert.ToDouble(list[9]);
                lineItem.PrtlDocNum = list[10].ToString();
                lineItem.PrtlUniqueID = list[11].ToString();

                ReconHdr.AddItem(lineItem);

            }
```